# Random number but with a bias

Tags: php, random

How would I go about creating a random number generator which has a bias to be within a range of numbers?
say I have this:

```
$rnum = rand(0,200);
```

so `$rnum == 3` and next time `$rnum == 106` then `$rnum == 10` and so on...

But I would rather have a bias range of say 80 - 120 so it would more likely select a number within the bias range than outside of it.

`$rnum == 86` and next time `$rnum == 112` then `$rnum == 93` but still be able to `$rnum == 24` and so on...

I thought I might have been able to do this:

```
if($rnum < $middle_of_bias){
    $rnum++;
}else{
    $rnum--;
}
```

but didn't really work, as you can see if `$rnum == 1` after applying the bias it would only make it `2` not making this method very successful.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit: everyones answers were great. I really liked *gnur's* one and *Phil H's* I have made my modifications to *rmflow's* one and it is working how I wanted it to.** *Thanks to every one that helped!*

```
if (rand(0, 10) > 2)
{
    $rnum = rand($low, $high);
}else{
    $rnum = rand(0, $max);
}
```

Comment: How much do you want to bias it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if (rand(0, 10) > 7)
{
    $rnum = rand(80, 120);
}
else
{
    $rnum = rand(0, 200);
}
```

Comment: Why did you choose rand(0,10)>7 ?

This would mean that 3 out of 11 times it is always in the bias range. The remaining 8 times have 20% chance of hitting the bias range (1.6 times)

So 4.6 times out of 11 is within the range. So the bias range would actually be hit less often then outside the bias range.

Comment: @hugo But per number it would be more often because just 20% of the numbers will be hit 41% of the time.

Comment: @gnur correct, there is a bigger chance of hitting them then any other number, but what I understood from the question is that he wants to hit a number in the bias range with higher then 50% chance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `rand()` to get a random number from a larger range in a uniform distribution and then use a function to map that larger range to the smaller range you actually want in a way that produces the distribution you want.

Comment: To create a normal distribution centered on 100 you would use an equation such as:

`100 + (200 * rand() - 100)`

Comment: Where the mean is 100 and the variance is 200.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility to bias your random number:

```
$rnum = rand(90,110);
$rex1 = 45 - rand(0,90);
$rex2 = 45 - rand(0,90);
$rbias = $rnum + $rex1 + rex2;
```

This will increase likeliness of numbers around 100, numbers of 0-10 and 190-200 are quite unlikely while numbers between 80-120 are very likely.

Answer (score 0):

Just add spare capacity to the end of the range and anything above the maximum you shift into the biased range.

```
$rnum = rand(0,240);
if($rnum > 200) {
    $rnum -= 120; // 201 -> 81
}
```

This will only double the probability of getting a value in that range. If you want more bias, extend the range further:

```
$rmax = 200;
$bmin = 80;
$bmax = 120;
$brange = $bmax - $bmin;
$nbias = 4;
$rnum = rand(0,$rmax+($brange*$nbias));
if($rnum > $rmax) {
    $excess -= $rmax; // 201 -> 81
    $remainder  = modulo($rnum,$brange);
    $rnum = $remainder+$bmin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create two ranges, one biased, one not.

```
not biased range: 0, 200
biased range:     80, 120
```

then pick a likeliness for getting a none biased number, say 20%. that's one 5th, or, 1 out of 5. then generate a random number between 1 and 5, if it comes out as 1, generate a random number from the none biased range. otherwise generate a number from the biased range.

since i started writing, a couple of answers has come in. the answer from rmflow describes my flow, but with a 36% likeliness of getting a none biased number.

good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining an array of $item=>$weight:

```
$biasedArray = array(
  'Blue'   => 50,
  'Yellow' => 30,
  'Pink'   => 10,
  'Green'  => 10,
);

chooseFromBiasedArray($biasArray);

function chooseFromBiasedArray($biasArray) {
  $totalWeight = array_sum($biasedArray);
  $randChoice = rand(1,$totalWeight);

  $currentWeight = 0;
  reset($biasedArray);
  while ($currentWeight < $randChoice) {
    $currentKey = key($biasedArray);

    $currentWeight += $biasedArray[$currentKey];
    if ($currentWeight < $randChoice) {
      next($biasedArray);
    }
  }

  //echo $randChoice . " -> " . current($biasArray);
  return current($biasArray);
}
```

I wrote it very fast, you can do it much cleaner but the idea will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @rmflow would be the way in which I would add a weighted bias to a range. However, I would use the mt_rand function for better randomness.

[mt_rand](https://www.php.net/mt_rand) — Generate a random value via the Mersenne Twister Random Number Generator.

It is also purported to be 4x faster ([This function produces a better random value, and is 4 times faster than rand()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_mt_rand.asp)), however, in my experience I see little only a 20% increase in performance.

```
if (mt_rand(0, 10) > 7)
{
    $rnum = mt_rand(80, 120);
}
else
{
    $rnum = mt_rand(0, 200);
}
```